# How to play two or more sounds at the same time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, audio, fmod, directsound

I'm quite new to programming, I'm in my first year of my programming; CS1B.

I'm making a text adventure game in Visual Studio 2015, I want to use two sounds, like music in the background and a sound effect.

But whenever I try to do so, the first sound stops when the second sound starts. I'm using the `PlaySound()` function to do my sounds. I know about `FMOD` and `DirectSound` but I don't really know how to set it up.

I tried looking through how to do this, but the stuff I find is really hard for me to follow. Any help will be good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your sounds into SFX and music (which uses the music system). This way, you can control your background music separately (as well as make use of their music-specific features) from your sound effect events.

In general, you need to have a separate event/sound instance for each of the sound you are playing. If you only have one, it could get 'stolen' and this might be the most possible reason for your problem. It could also be because of your channels.

I am not sure if you are using FMOD Studio or FMOD Designer/FMOD Ex, though, so it really depends on which one you are using. In any case, if you are just starting, I recommend reading up on the **FMOD Event System - Best Practices For Programmers**
documentation which you can get from the Internet, as well as the **FMOD Ex Programmer's API** documentation (you will have to have an account to download this, but it's worth it.)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`PlaySound` only has a single 'voice' to work with, so it can't play more than one sound at a time.

To play more than one sound at a time requires a real-time mixer, so you need to use something else: XAudio2, FMOD, Wwise, MSS, OpenAL, etc.

> DirectSound is deprecated and hasn't been updated since 2000. It still exists for BackCompat but has a number of restrictions and other subtle legacy behaviors. The only reason anyone should still be using DirectSound at all is if they are targeting Windows XP.

If you are using C++, you should look at [DirectX Tool Kit for Audio](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Audio) which is a simple C++ wrapper for XAudio2.

Answer (score -1):

I would guess simple multithreading would do:

```
#include <thread>
...
thread playsound(&playsound, this, <other params>);
playsound.detach();
thread othersound(&playsound, this, <other params>);
othersound.detach();
```

Good luck